# How to get all records from Today and Yesterday's date in Firestore Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**I wanna get the previous day and today's record please help me out thanks I am storing date like this.**

```
    static final DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.now();
          static final DateTime yesterdayDate =
              DateTime.utc(todaysDate.year, todaysDate.month, todaysDate.day - 1);
          final String formatte = formatter.format(yesterdayDate);  


**Here is my controller to get data from the firebase.**
  
final controller = ScreenshotController();
      final Stream<QuerySnapshot> otherStream =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('lott').snapshots();
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: otherStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print('Something went Wrong');
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
    


     final List storedocs = [];
      snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        storedocs.add(a);
        a['id'] = document.id;
      }).toList();
```

Any example would be great and If you can also highlight how to get specific results would also be great.

Comment: Hi, did Sajad Abdollahi's answer help you?

Comment: Most of my data is coming in the form of a list in the table so doing in that form and implementing would be great

Answer (score 3):

You should add an extra field called `createdAt` in your documents and store the creation date of this document in it.
ex:

```dart
'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

Then you can simply query Firestore like this

```dart
Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getRecentDocs() async {

  final Timestamp now = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());
  final Timestamp yesterday = Timestamp.fromDate(
    DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
  );

  final query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('collectionPath')
      .where('createdAt', isLessThan: now, isGreaterThan: yesterday);

  return query.get();
}
```

Read more about Firestore queries and limitations here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: ok thanks will try